# Datastore Form Data Insert Help Please

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Goal is to get "name", "mood" variables, and date, into Datastore. All I see worthwhile in Datastore is a crypto looking Entity key and Visitor-name-mood-date Index with no data, despite my submitting web form several times.

Here is form

First Name:

Select

Good

Bad

Fair

Running this in DS Console gives me

> ameError: name 'visitor' is not defined

```
q = Visitor.all()
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Visitor")  #in DS Console
results = q.fetch(2)
for p in results:
    print "%s" % (p.name)

#DATASTORE v v
class Visitor(db.Model):                   # index.py
    name = db.StringProperty()
    mood = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

 class Post(webapp.RequestHandler):           #yaris
  def get(self):
    visitor_db = Visitor()
    visitor_db.name = self.request.get("name")
    visitor_db.mood = self.request.get("mood")
    visitor_db.put()
```

and index.yaml:

```
indexes:                              # seems like this is OK

-   kind: Visitor 
    properties:
    -   name: name
    -   name: mood
    -   name: date
        direction: asc
```

Also getting 405 errors in terminal when submitting form.

**EDIT**: got this working with the following; thanks for help.

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""<html><body>
<form action="/" method="post">
                           # form is here
</body></html> """) 

        name = self.request.get("name")
        name = name.capitalize()
        mood = self.request.get("mood")
        localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
        mon = localtime[1] # MONTH
        h = localtime[3] # HOUR

        # if/elif statements with %s specifiers follow...still in MainPage class v v

> def post(self):
>         name = self.request.get("name")
>         name = name.capitalize()
>         mood = self.request.get("mood")
>         info = Visitor(name = name, mood = mood)
>         info.put()
>         self.redirect("/index.py")
```

This stores data in Datastore! Now, the only thing I need to fix is to **get the form responses to print on the original form page (index.py)**, in the proper div, which I have float-right next to the form. Instead, the form-submitted responses are appearing on a different, unformatted page. I have played with the self.redirect, and the following, but I need some direction how to implement this or even if I"m the right path, to get form responses to print on the form page, not on a different page:

## Created handler

```
    redirectionHandler = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler() 

    # 2 apply the handler to an opener
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirectionHandler)

    # 3. Install the openers
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)


    request = urllib2.Request("http://*my url*", #commented out     data=urllib.urlencode({'key':'value'}))
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Did you try to run the query in the Datastore viewer of the admin console? It suggests you what indexes you need to create.

Comment: I did run this in admin console.

Comment: I updated my answer.. maybe it's the post(self) since you have a form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not creating any entity to be able to `put()`. Try this to begin with:

```
class Post(webapp.RequestHandler):   
  def post(self):
    visitor_db = Visitor()
    visitor_db.name = self.request.get("name")
    visitor_db.mood = self.request.get("mood")
    visitor_db.put()
```

The above code will create one new entry and store it.

I updated my answer, if you're using a form to submit data, then you should change the `get(self)` to `post(self)` since browser is requesting a `POST` request upon form submission.

Comment: thank you Lipis, yes I think the post request was a problem. I have updated my original code above to show how I got this working. That's for your help!

Comment: @pavl go through your old questions and do the same.. if there is no answer improve question or delete if solved without an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the right idea, but you should debug ApplyHandler.post(), most likely your problem is there.  You may be missing the post data in your request and the newuser object may be initialized with a bunch of None data.

Comment: thanks...what exactly would I do with ApplyHandler? this script is not reading the form values that I am able to use otherwise from name = form.getvalue("name")

Comment: Are you saying that self.request.get("name") returns an empty value? If so, I think you want to concentrate on your form code instead of on the datastore.

Comment: thanks for replies...I have updated code, and I am unsure how to test ApplyHandler.(post) and self.request.get("name") as Submit button does not function when Firebug is open for this application...no errors thrown, app is functioning otherwise.

Comment: Then the problem is in your HTML form submission.  You haven't posted your HTML form here, so we can't help you with that.

Comment: how do I select 2 answers as being helpful?

Comment: You can only select one correct answer, whichever is best to you.  You can upvote multiple answers though.